# Are there any contexts / situations in ES6 Modules where it wouldn't work to update var to let?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, variable-declaration

For some time now, I've used `const` to declare most variables.

If I don't absolutely know for certain that a new variable will always hold the same value, I will declare the new variable with `let`.

I almost never use `var`.

That's me.

However, any other individual writing javascript will have their own preferred variable declaration conventions and, if I am accepting **user-generated-content** such as *User Written ES6 Modules* there's no way predict with confidence what those conventions might be.

---

Leaving aside `const` for the moment...

### `var` can be overwritten by `var`:

I know that the following:

- `var myString = 'My String declared with var';`
- `var myFunction = function() {console.log('My Function declared with var')};`

can be overwritten with identically named variables declared with `var`.

**Example:**

```js
var myString = 'My String declared with var';
var myFunction = function() {console.log('My Function declared with var')};

var myString = 'My Overwriting String declared with var';
var myFunction = function() {console.log('My Overwriting Function declared with var')};

console.log(myString);
myFunction();
```

### `let` *cannot* be overwritten by `var`:

I also know that if `myString` and `myFunction` are declared with `let`

- `let myString = 'My String declared with let';`
- `let myFunction = function() {console.log('My Function declared with let')};`

they cannot subsequently be overwritten with `var`, `let`, or `const`.

**Example:**

```js
let myString = 'My String declared with let';
let myFunction = function() {console.log('My Function declared with let')};

var myString = 'My Overwriting String declared with var';
var myFunction = function() {console.log('My Overwriting Function declared with var')};

console.log(myString);
myFunction();
```

So, knowing both these things, is it a reasonable safeguard to convert any `var` declarations to `let` declarations (either at compile time or at runtime) in all *User Submitted ES6 Modules*?

Are there any conceivable contexts / situations in ES6 Modules where it wouldn't work to update `var` to `let`?

Comment: They're scoped differently.  I would think that would be enough to preclude a simple transliteration, unless you told your Users to expect this to happen.

Comment: Right. Good point. I suppose it's too difficult for any of us to say that just because someone is writing an _ES6 Module_, it doesn't mean they definitely aren't writing as if block scope isn't a thing in JS.

Comment: Is this something that can be solved with a warning message to users? "Please use `const/let`, `var` will not be accepted." It's acceptable to assume `var` is basically deprecated in ES6 (not literally, but any developer up to date knows this) these days

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding, but your given examples already make it impossible to safely convert all `var` to `let` - any code using `var` to declare a variable multiple times will error out. In addition to this there is the scope issue as pointed out by Robert. I think those are the only differences, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user wrote a function like this, changing var to let would fail:

```js
function run() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  console.log('final i', i);
}

console.log('starting run');
run();

function runLet() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(i);
  }
  console.log('final i', i);
}

console.log('starting runLet');
runLet();
```

the runLet function errors because i is undefined.

Comment: Thank you, @TKoL. Yes, that's a perfect illustration of the scope issue that Robert Harvey mentioned in the comments beneath the question.